# How can I define a global field in a ModuleBuilder

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I'm making dynamic assemblies with `System.Reflection.Emit`, and I want to define a module-level field, the kind that can be retrieved with [`Module.GetField`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st1k9h88(v=vs.110).aspx0). There are methods in `ModuleBuilder` to define global methods, but the only thing I could find that looked like a "`DefineGlobalField`" method are [`DefineInitializedData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.modulebuilder.defineinitializeddata(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`DefineUninitializedData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.modulebuilder.defineuninitializeddata(v=vs.110).aspx), but for these I specify a size (or initial value, from which the size can be inferred) rather than a type. How can I do this?

Comment: huh; I've never noticed that (the `GetField` with no matching `DefineField` etc); I love this question! That said; using a static type (TypeBuilder) with static fields *there* might be a pragmatic workaround

Comment: I had considered doing that, but for what I'm doing I wanted something like what F# does, where you can define global functions and variables, but in order to have them accessible them outside the assembly you need to put them in a static class. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 1):

After some sifting through the source code of the `reflection.emit` classes, I discovered that global methods are actually written to a `TypeBuilder` hiding behind the `ModuleBuilder` interface. You're really not supposed to be able to access it, but if you get ahold of it via reflection, any fields (and methods) you define on it will become module-global (if you try to define properties or events, no errors will be thrown, but as far as I can tell they don't actually get defined). This is a working solution, but it's obvious you're not supposed to do it, so if anyone comes up with a better one, please post it. In the meantime, here's the code for it:

```
var moduleData = myModule.GetType().GetField("m_moduleData", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(myModule);
var globalTypeBuilder = (TypeBuilder) moduleData.GetType().GetField("m_globalTypeBuilder", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(moduleData);
globalTypeBuilder.DefineField("myGlobalVar", typeof(int), FieldAttributes.Public | FieldAttributes.Static);
myModule.CreateGlobalFunctions();
```

Note a) that any fields or methods defined on `globalTypeBuilder` must be static, b) that there's no advantage that I can tell of defining methods on `globalTypeBuilder` rather that just using `Module.DefineGlobalMethod`, and c) even when using `globalTypeBuilder` you still need to call `Module.CreateGlobalFunctions`, whether for global methods, global fields, or both.